# How to find the link of an embedded YouTube video

Tags: youtube

I have tried to get a link from an embedded YouTube video but I can't seem to find it. The video can be found at this link: http://www.acg-tube.com/the-italian-job-2003/
Could you explain to me how to find it? I tried using 'Inspect this element', view page source and view page info but the only link I found was this one https://video.google.com/get_player?el=leaf&cc_load_policy=1&enablejsapi=1 which is not a YouTube link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message  ("Unable to play this video at this time. The number of allowed playbacks has been exceeded. Please try again later.") that I found playing another movie, I got to know that the movie is hosted on Google Drive and not YouTube. As such there is no YouTube embed code.